# PHP $$var['index'] = something; fails, although I thought it would work just like $$var = something; does

Tags: php, syntax

I was trying to use the $$ syntax in PHP for accessing arrays where we can put name of a variable inside another variable and access that variable.

I have used this syntax many times before in different ways, but to my surprise this didn't work for me and lost lot of time over it.

Here is sample code to replicate my problem:

```
$test=array(
'a'=>array(array(1,2,3),array(4,5,6),array(7,8,9))
);

$var = 'test';
var_dump($$var);
var_dump($$var['a']);
```

The line `var_dump($$var)` works as expected, but I'm getting a Warning: Illegal string offset 'a' at line `var_dump($$var['a']);` and the var_dump prints just `null`

Why doesn't this work? What am I doing wrong here?
Is there any work around if the syntax is not supported for arrays?

Comment: Use `${$var}['a']` instead (see Gordon's answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$$var['a']` is equivalent to `${$var['a']}`. Not `${$var}['a']`. The latter being the workaround syntax you are looking for.

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

See http://codepad.org/lR7QJygX

Comment: Ah! I'm ashamed I didn't try reading the official PHP documentation! which is what I usually do first. Thanks a lot for the answer.